# Difference between security-realm and security-domain in WildFly

Tags: jboss, wildfly, wildfly-8

What is the main difference between security-domain and security-realm in WildFly?

**standalone.xml**

```
               <security-domain name="foo">             
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module code="..." flag="...">                           
                        </login-module>                                         
                    </authentication>
                </security-domain>
```

and

```
        <security-realm name="foo">
            <authentication>
                <local default-user="..." allowed-users="..." 
skip-group-loading="..."/>
                <properties path="..." relative-to="..."/>
            </authentication>
            <authorization>
                <properties path="..." relative-to="..."/>
            </authorization>
        </security-realm>
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

*Answer updated (2018-06-08) to reflect WildFly Elytron naming. WildFly Elytron is a new security subsystem introduced in WildFly 11 (and JBoss EAP 7.1). Both security subsystems - legacy one and the Elytron - have notion of security domains and security realms but the meaning is different.*

#### Legacy security

The **Security Domains** are used mainly for defining security of deployed applications.
The standard authentication in security domains is based on [JAAS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jaas/JAASRefGuide.html) `javax.security.auth.spi.LoginModule` implementations. Application can come up with custom login module(s).

The **Security Realms** are used mainly for configuration security of server management interfaces and remoting.
The realm authentication is based on provided implementations of `javax.security.auth.callback.CallbackHandler`. AFAIK it's not possible to provide own CallbackHandler implementation.

A security domain can delegate authentication to a security realm by using the **"RealmDirect"** login module.

A security realm can delegate authentication to a security domain by using **"jaas"** authentication configuration

See also [this response](https://developer.jboss.org/message/753510#753510) by JBoss security developer Darran Lofthouse.

#### Elytron security

The **Security Realms** encapsulate access to user repositories (DB - jdbc-realm, LDAP - ldap-realm, property file - properties-realm, ...). Compared to legacy security it's on a similar level as JAAS Login Modules. An API is provided so custom realms can be implemented.

The **Security Domain** represents a security policy which uses Security Realms for authentication. Security domains can be used in management security as well as in the application security. A successful authentication against a security domain produces a `SecurityIdentity` which represents the current user.

Read [Elytron subsystem](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.1/html/security_architecture/eap_security_out_of_the_box#elytron_subsystem) chapter in JBoss EAP documentation to get a more detailed overview of Elytron components.

To learn more about controlling authentication flow in Elytron security domains read [this article](http://darranl.blogspot.com/2017/07/wildfly-elytron-principal-transformers.html) from Darran Lofthouse.

#### In the middle between Legacy and Elytron security

If you are migrating from Legacy to Elytron security, you can expose a **Legacy Security Domain** as an **Elytron Security Realm**. Read more about this scenario in the Elytron Subsystem [Migration guide](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY/Migrate+Legacy+Security+to+Elytron+Security#MigrateLegacySecuritytoElytronSecurity-IntermediateConfiguration)

Comment: In the application's web.xml, you can define a realm name for your login-config. However, if my application uses a security-domain, what does the realm-name specified in the web.xml do?

Comment: The realm-name in web.xml is just a name presented to clients  authenticating to your application. You can see this name in a browser authentication dialog during BASIC authentication.